# Tell Netbeans it's a Ruby file

Tags: ruby, netbeans

I've got a file named Vagrantfile and it's a ruby file but it cannot have the .rb at the end of the filename.

Is there a way to tell Netbeans that it's Ruby file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the file in Files view (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>) and look for "`Open As...`". When the context menu opens, select "`text/x-ruby`". Note that this works only when a file type is not detected automatically.
There is a caveat with this: Once a file w/o extension is opened as Ruby file, it treats all files w/o extension as Ruby files.

Comment: Great trick, but since it will tread all files with no extension it's probably not a such good idea:)

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering this myself today, and came up with this:

```
# Vagrantfile.rb
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "base"
  # ...
end
```

and

```
# Vagrantfile
require "Vagrantfile.rb"
```

It's just Ruby after all!