# How can I tell NetBeans that a .html file is actually Twig?

Tags: netbeans

I have the Twig plugin installed, and NetBeans correctly colours `.twig` files, and offers code completion options. However, for some reason, our source code contains a bunch of `.html` files which are actually Twig. I don’t know why it was built this way, but it’s too late to change it now.

I know how to [change the displayed syntax highlighting in Gedit](https://askubuntu.com/q/916083), but not in NetBeans. A similar question on [files without extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3571889) was answered with a workaround. And, obviously, not all `.html` files are Twig; just some of them.